# Grant all user access to one Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, user-controls

Is it possible in MySql to create an Database where everyone on the Server has read access ? Or do i have I to do it for each user separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try granting to this user with wildcards:

```
'%'@'%'
```

Comment: i did it with ''@localhost, you helped a lot thow to get me on the right path ;-)